# How do I setup Sourcetree without Kiln having to enter a username and password every time I push/pull?

Tags: osx-lion, repository, tortoise-hg

I have a Kiln account that I use to manage my repository.  However, I've noticed that everytime SourceTree accesses my Kiln account I have to enter in my username and password at least 3-4 times.  I've checked the box that says "Save pass in your keychain", but this does nothing to stop the behavior.

I've removed the entry in keychain and tried to pull a new clone of the repository, but now I receive the following error:

```
warning: <sub domain>.kilnhg.com certificate with fingerprint fe:ad:65:89:5f:6f:1a:21:a8:33:45:6c:2a:cb:ca:bd:e9:e5:f0:01 not verified (check hostfingerprints or web.cacerts config setting)
```

And I still have to enter the username/password multiple times.

As there appears to be two parts to this situation, here is what I'm looking for:

1. How do I register kiln's certificate so that I don't receive the error above?
2. How do I properly setup Keychain to work properly with Sourcetree and Kiln?

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to your question, and I can answer the certificate one.  This appears to be a new 'feature' of mercurial:

> Mercurial has improved its HTTPS support in the 1.7.x series. When
>   connecting to an HTTPS server, it will now verify the server's
>   certificate correctly and reject the connection if the server identity
>   can't be confirmed - but only if Certification Authorities (CAs) have
>   been configured. **As of 1.7.3, Mercurial will warn if CAs haven't been
>   configured.**

This error will actually happen on ALL platforms that aren't configured correctly.  I suggest looking at [this wiki in regards to CA Certificates](http://mercurial.selenic.com/wiki/CACertificates) for more details.  For Mac OS X 10.6 and higher do the following:

1. In terminal run the following code:

   - `openssl req -new -x509 -extensions v3_ca -keyout /dev/null -out dummycert.pem -days 3650`

   This will create a 'dummy' certificate.  It doesn't matter what you enter as values
2. Next, copy the newly created cert to /etc:

   - `sudo cp dummycert.pem /etc/hg-dummy-cert.pem`
3. Finally change the web configuration of the source tree repository:

   - Open the Kiln repository
   - Select Settings in the top right corner of the opened repo
   - Select "Edit Config File..."
   - Paste the following into the bottom of the file:

     - `[web]`
       `cacerts = /etc/hg-dummy-cert.pem`